# Why Google AdSense not showing with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, adsense

I'm trying to implement a simple banner Ad with Google AdSense inside my React website. I used create-react-app.

I've created a component wrapping the banner:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AdBanner extends Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        console.log('DID IT!!');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <ins className="adsbygoogle"
                style={{ display: "block"}}
                data-ad-format="fluid"
                data-ad-layout-key="-fb+5w+4e-db+86"
                data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx">
            </ins>
        );
    }
}
export default AdBanner;
```

And I've added the following script inside the `<head>` tag of my index.html file

```html
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

## The problem ##
The Ad is not showing up in any way! The compiler is ok and browser does not give any message in the console (apart of 'DID IT!'. **I've created the Ad in the console two days ago.**

I've tried also deactivating React strict mode.

Thankssssss

Comment: You must add billing&Payment method.
check this if you still have doubts- https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2375433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `ad is not showing up` - do you see empty white rectangle where ad should be? Also do you see `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?` requests in network tab? If so - how many? If you see 2 then ad requests are made and what might be happening is that AdSense didn't find a good ad, which is normal. You can also try adding `data-adtest="on"` to the `<ins>` tag which might help to force an ad.

Comment: Yes, I see an empty white rect. There are two calls to googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads in the net tab and I added data-adtest="on", but still no Ad.

Comment: Hi @NiccolòSegato, I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve this issue?